# The action of doing something ( definition)

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I do not understand the definition of " The action of going back to work " Are we talking about the action or actions one does to go back to work or are we just talking about going back to work?

And i thought we used the preposition "of" while talking about possession. Is this the case right now ?

Comment: It's 'dictionary language' for 'This word means _going back to work_'. _Of_ has many uses and does not refer to possession in this case.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting Thank you so much. I think going back to work is the idea and the action of going back to work is the process. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you could put it like that.